# How to remove extra array in arrays list in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, xml, laravel

## Screenshot

[image: one]

As you see my data are loaded inside extra `SNHISTORY` array and I need to remove that extra array.

## Code

> Lines regarding to screenshot results are commented.

```
$array = [];
foreach($internalTransits as $key => $item) {
    foreach($item->barcodes as $barcode){}
    $a = $item->barcodes;
    $grouped = $a->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
        return [
            'SNHISTORY' => [ // my arrays to move out
                '_attributes' => [
                    'operation' => 'Ret'
                ],
                'SERIALNUMBER' => $item['serial_number'] ? $item['serial_number'] : $item['u_serial_number'],
                'EXPIREDDATE' => $item['created_at']->format('Y-m-d'),
                'QUANTITY' => '1',
                'SNSIGN' => '-1',
            ],
            'ITEMUNIT' => $item['product']['unit'],
            'UNITPRICE' => $item['product']['price'],
        ];
    });

    $year = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['created_at'])->year;
    $month = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['created_at'])->month;

    $timeline[$key][] = [
        '_attributes' => [
            'operation' => 'Add'
        ],
        'KeyID' => $barcode['product']['id'],
        'ITEMNO' => $barcode['product']['sku'],
        'QUANTITY' => '1',
        'ITEMUNIT' => $barcode['product']['unit'],
        'UNITRATIO' => '1',
        'ITEMRESERVED1' => '',
        'ITEMRESERVED2' => '',
        'ITEMRESERVED3' => '',
        'ITEMRESERVED4' => '',
        'ITEMRESERVED5' => '',
        'ITEMRESERVED6' => '',
        'ITEMRESERVED7' => '',
        'ITEMRESERVED8' => '',
        'ITEMRESERVED9' => '',
        'ITEMRESERVED10' => '',
        'UNITPRICE' => $barcode['product']['price'],
        'QTYCONTROL' => '0',
        'SNHISTORY' => $grouped->toArray(), // this has extra array where my actual arrays are loaded inside of it
    ];

    $array['TRANSACTIONS'] = [
        '_attributes' => [
            'OnError' => 'CONTINUE'
        ],
    ];

    $array['TRANSACTIONS']['WTRAN'] = [
        '_attributes' => [
            'operation' => 'Add',
            'REQUESTID' => '1',
        ],
        'TRANSFERID' => $item['id'],
        'TRANSACTIONID' => '',
        'TRANSFERNO' => $item['transNu'],
        'TRANSFERDATE' => $item['created_at']->format('Y-m-d'),
        'DESCRIPTION' => $item['description'],
        'FROMWHID' => $barcode['outlet'][0]['name'],
        'TOWHID' => $item->toOutlet->name,
        'FROMWHADDRESS' => '',
        'TOWHADDRESS' => '',
    ];

    $array['TRANSACTIONS']['WTRAN']['ITEMLINE'] = $timeline;
}
```

#### What I've tried

1. I cannot change `'SNHISTORY' => $grouped->toArray(),` to something like `$grouped->toArray(),` under `$timeline[$key][] = [` it will return error
2. I cannot add `$array['TRANSACTIONS']['WTRAN']['ITEMLINE']['SNHISTORY'] = $grouped->toArray();` and remove `'SNHISTORY' => $grouped->toArray(),` it will return error [known bug](https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+Invalid+Character+Error)

#### Question

**How can I remove extra `SNHISTORY` around my data?**

Comment: in your screen shot u have xml data u need to convert in to array

Comment: `$timeline[$key][] = [...] + $grouped->toArray();`? You want to merge those.

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes it's converting my database data to xml, the problem is I don't need that extra `SNHISTORY` around my data.

Comment: @Jeto sorry I didn't catch what you're trying to say

Comment: [I mean like this.](https://3v4l.org/0odI7) (sorry, without the SNHISTORY key, edited)

Comment: @mafortis that is not extra key if u pare correct way into array i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, you probably want to merge both arrays together:

```
$timeline[$key][] = [
    '_attributes' => [
        'operation' => 'Add'
    ],
    'KeyID' => $barcode['product']['id'],
    'ITEMNO' => $barcode['product']['sku'],
    'QUANTITY' => '1',
    'ITEMUNIT' => $barcode['product']['unit'],
    'UNITRATIO' => '1',
    'ITEMRESERVED1' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED2' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED3' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED4' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED5' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED6' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED7' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED8' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED9' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED10' => '',
    'UNITPRICE' => $barcode['product']['price'],
    'QTYCONTROL' => '0',
] + $grouped->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

as i can see in your screen shot `data`
you are getting xml data you need to convert that into  array

```php
 function xmlToArray($xml_string)
    {
        $doc = @simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
        if ($doc) {
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
            $json = json_encode($xml);
            return json_decode($json, true);
        }
    }
```

then u will get real array then u don't need to remove that as that is a parent key

Comment: thanks it's already fixed by `Jeto` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63666139/how-to-remove-extra-array-in-arrays-list-in-laravel#comment112582285_63666139)